# Looking for a wordpress referral plugin that counts the referral after an action is performed

Tags: plugins

I am in need of a plugin where, when user A refers user B and user B completes a certain action on the site, he is counted as a referral of user A.I am not looking for a simple "user A refers user B so user B is user As referral" kind of thing.Is there a plugin for that or should I be looking to get an affiliate program for my site?I'm very sorry if a similar question was asked before but I really didn't know how to search for it and get anything relevant :S .

Comment: Asking for a plugin is off-topic here. We are here to discuss about code. :)

Comment: Sorry, I saw a similar question posted before and I hurriedly asked before bothering to read the FAQ..Silly of me.Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup a cookie once a user referred by someone joins your website. Then once someone performs an action, check if he has that cookie and register it as a referral. You can use [JavaScript to setup the cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1460174/691525).